# what is proper way to switch stubview layout that has been inflated already?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have a simple relative layout included two stubview looks like below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ViewStub
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_login"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout="@layout/layout_main_login"/>

    <ViewStub
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_member"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout="@layout/layout_main_member"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

after two stubviews has been inflated, what is the proper way to switch inflated layout visible or gone agagin? I am a little confused, since the stubview removed from parent view hierarchy, the stubview will be null at that point.

I have took a look at 
https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html
and 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html

am I misunderstand some points, that stubview once inflated will not be able to set visible or gone again?

my walkaround is wrap the stubview by famelayout or other layout, and change the visiblity of that layout.

Answer (score 1):

In the similar situation I use the following code:

```
View layoutInflated;

void setStubViewVisibility(final boolean visible) {
    if (null == layoutInflated) {
        if (visible) {
            layoutInflated= ((ViewStub) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_login)).inflate();
            layoutInflated.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        layoutInflated.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

So you don't have to place `ViewStub` into another layout. Just check if layout has been inflated.

Comment: this code can run without problem, switch viewstub this way will inflate stubview again and set visibility, which makes no difference with load view at once rather than on demand, but I prefer your apporch rather than wrap stubview into another layout

Comment: What do you mean "switch viewstub this way will inflate stubview again"? Each `ViewStub` will be inflated only once. Of course you have to modify my example and pass layoutId as a method param

Comment: oh, I mean for example setLoginViewVisibility(true); setMemberViewVisibility(false);